# Differences between Insert & Delete for singly linked lists with sentinel nodes

Tags: singly-linked-list, pseudocode

We were assigned with the task of coding the Insert(L,k) & Delete(L,k) functions for a singly-linked list with a sentinel node. My questions are:

1. Is it correct or close to the right answer?
2. assuming what i've done is correct, i'm not
   seeing any significant difference from a normal Delete() of a singly
   linked list without a sentinel node. Am i correct in that statement?

Description of Insert(L,k):

> The function inserts a new node with key == k in the list (if it doesn't already exist).

Description of Delete(L,k):

> The function looks for the node whose key == k and if it finds it, it deletes it.

We can assume that the key of each node is unique.

My implementation of Insert:

```
fun Insert(pointer L,Key k) {
    pointer p;
    pointer currNode = L; // first element

    while(currNode != NULL && currNode->data != k) {
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }

    if(currNode == NULL) { // element doesn't exist
        p = newcell(Node); // allocate memory for a new node
        p->data = k;
        p->next  = L;
        L = p;
        return;
    }
    else { // element exists
        throw error;
    }
}
```

My implementation of Delete:

```
    fun Delete(pointer L, Key k) {
        pointer currNode = L; //first element
        pointer prev = NULL; // A pointer to the previous node

    if(currNode != NULL && currNode->data == k) { // first elemenent has k
        L = currNode->next;
        free(currNode);
    }

    // look for the elemenent to delete
    while(currNode->next != NULL && currNode->data != k) {
        prev = currNode;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }

    if(currNode->next == NULL) throw error; // element not found

    // elemenent found
    prev->next = currNode->next;
    free(currNode);
}
```

P.S. Here's how a singly linked list with a sentinel node looks like in our examples
[image]

Comment: Hi Stelios, As I can see you code is working. So, feel free to ask this question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Check an example https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210685/rsa-c-implementation. Most of the times code reviews here are on fire!

Comment: Also, I would love to review this code.